# If I set a header in a message handler in Nservicebus should the header value be available to downstream handlers?

Tags: nservicebus

I have a message type that is handled by two different handlers (with the order specified by `ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering`).

If I set a header inside the first handler, say `message.SetHeader("SomeStatus", "value");` should I then be able to call `message.GetHeader("SomeStatus")` in the second hander and get the value set?

It's currently not working for me, `GetHeader` is just returning null, but I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if this shouldn't work anyway.

I'm using nservicebus 3.2.5

Comment: As a workaround you can use Bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers to set and retreive your header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - this is a bug. Logged as #529 and will be fixed as part of the next release.

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/529